# User Rights issues with two new desktops Windows 2003 SBS domain

Tags: windows-server-2003

I do IT support for a small company of 6 users, they are running a  Windows 2003 SBS Domain.

Two new machines were added recently, a Windows 7 Professional machine and a Windows XP client machine, both machines cannot install software and one cannot create new folders on the desktop.

All other desktops in the building can install software and create folders.

I have checked the following:

- Both machines are in Active Directory
- Both machines have the same Security groups as the other machines.
- The users operating the machines can install software on other
  machines in the building.
- Both Users  have the same security groups as the other users.

What else could cause an issue such as this?

Comment: The issue with the folders has been resolved as a replication issue. Still having trouble with the ability to install software.